# Combine a list of functions into a single function using fold

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, fold

Lets say I have a list of functions

```
let plus_one (x: int) : int = x + 1 in
let double (x: int) : int = x * 2 in
let square (x: int) : int = x * x in
let fun_list = [square, double, plus_one] ;;
```

Using fold, I want to take this list of functions and combine them into a single function. Something like,

```
let combined (x: int) : int = x * (2 * (x + 1))
```

This is what I have:

```
let combine_functions (fun_list : ('a -> 'a) list) : ('a -> 'a) =
    List.fold_right (fun f acc -> f acc) fun_list (fun x -> x)
;;
```

I would think this would work, however when I try to run this, it tells me that this expression has type 'a -> 'a when it should have type ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by changing the second line of code from

```
List.fold_right (fun f acc -> f acc) fun_list (fun x -> x)
```

to

```
List.fold_right (fun f acc -> (fun x -> f (acc x))) fun_list (fun x -> x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear on what sort of combination you want, do you mean [functional composition?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) If that's the case, then your combined function would look something like this:

`square (double (plus_one x))`

or

`((x + 1) * 2) * ((x + 1) * 2)`

which could be achieved by the function

```
let combine_functions ls =
  List.fold_right (fun f x -> f x) ls;;
```

However I'm not totally sure if this is really what you're trying to do. As an aside, you don't need to explicitly type all your OCaml code, and I personally find that I'm more productive when I let the type inference do it for me.